# windows activation and repaving

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

If I choose to repave my windows 7 ultimate installation that has already been activiated am I going to be able to activate it again after the re-install?  I have not changed the hardware at all since the first install, so if there is some sort of hardware fingerprint that goes along with the activation then I assume it would be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activation should work without problems.  I've done this a number of times (re-installing Windows 7 on the same hardware because SpyWare ruined it beyond repair, or the hard drive failed {and only the new hard drive was the different equipment}).

If a lot of hardware changes, you'll be prompted with the option to make a toll-free call to Microsoft's Activation Centre which is open 24-hours a day, 7 days a week, where the staff will be able to help you get it going by providing you with an activation code that will work.